# Mui popover not showing in the currect position

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, popover, react-big-calendar

I'm using react big calendar and trying to make a popover when the user clicks any event. The issue is the popover is not showing in the correct position (the correct position will be the event where it was clicked). I think it causes the re-rendering issue or the popover can't able to get the selected event position.

kinda confused about how to solve this problem.

I'm attaching the relevant code for reference.

**Code**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import Popover from '@mui/material/Popover';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

const now = new Date();
const { Panel } = Collapse;
const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment)


const { confirm } = Modal;

function CalendarNew() {
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

    const handlePopover = (event, target) => {
        console.log('popover clicked', target)

        setAnchorEl(1);
    };

    const closePopover = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const id = open ? 'popover-trigger-click-root-close' : undefined;
 return (
<div>

 <Calendar
                views={['month']}
                popup={true}
                localizer={localizer}
                events={isEvents}
                style={{ height: 720 }}
                selectable={true}
                onSelectEvent={handlePopover}
                
            />


  <Popover
                style={{ opacity: 1 }}
                id={id}
                open={open}
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                onClose={closePopover}
                transformOrigin={{ horizontal: 636, vertical: 879 }}
           
            >
                <Typography sx={{ p: 2 }}>The content of the Popover.</Typography>
 </Popover>

</div>

    )
}
export default CalendarNew;
```

**Screenshot**

> In the screenshot the popover should show in the event but showing in the top left corner.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue with React Fullcalendar and I could show the popover this way;

```tsx
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "simple-popover" : undefined;
  const popoverTop = anchorEl?.getBoundingClientRect().top || 0;
  const popoverLeft = anchorEl?.getBoundingClientRect().left || 0;
 
   const handlePopoverClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };
 
   const handleEventClick = () => {
    setAnchorEl(event.el);
  };
  
    return (
      <Stack width={"100%"} p={4}>
        <Calendar
          events={events}
          dateClick={handleDateClick}
          eventContent={CalendarEventContent}
          eventClick={handleEventClick}
          headerToolbar={{
            left: "title",
            center: "",
            right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay prev,next",
          }}
        />
        <Popover
          anchorReference="anchorPosition"
          anchorPosition={{ top: popoverTop, left: popoverLeft }}
          id={id}
          open={open}
          onClose={handlePopoverClose}
          anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: "center",
            horizontal: "left",
          }}
          transformOrigin={{
            vertical: "center",
            horizontal: "right",
          }}
        >
          <Typography sx={{ p: 2 }}>The content of the Popover.</Typography>
        </Popover>
      </Stack>
  );
```

[image: React full calendar material ui popover]

Answer (score -1):

It's because you set `anchorEl` to `1`.

You need to set this `anchorEl` to a `dom element`, please read docs: https://mui.com/components/popover/#main-content

In the documentation of [react-big-calendar prop-onSelectEvent](https://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-onSelectEvent) you see that the `SyntheticEvent` is the second argument. Try to log it and get the `currentTarget` (or the `currentElement dom`).

So you just replace your function to this:

```js
    const handlePopover = (_, event) => {
        // NO: setAnchorEl(1)
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but if I set AnchorEl to event.currentTarget, the popover is not showing at all.

Comment: If i console log the event.currentTarget it shows undefined, no idea why it's happening like that.

Comment: What library do you use for Calendar? If the library doesn't send the `dom element` you can't use Mui Popover

Comment: I used react-big-calendar.

Comment: Yo you need to read the documentation about React-big-calendar and get the `dom element` of your cell on click... If your library doesn't give you that, you need to change